# With reference to orthonormal bases, can someone explain this please?

Tags: vectors, linear-algebra

$e_i$ and $e_j$ are orthonormal bases.

$a$ is a vector; $$a = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i e_i. $$

Question is, how the operation below equals $a_j$

\begin{align}\langle e_j|a\rangle&= \sum_{i=1}^N\langle e_j|a_i e_i\rangle\\&= \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \langle e_j|e_i\rangle \\ &= a_j .\end{align}

This might be a trivial question to some people, but much thanks to anyone who can explain and write out the explanation.

Comment: Which step in the derivation do you not understand? To me, you've written out a complete proof, so it might be helpful to know which step doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: You should use a more consistent notation. It may help to understand better what is going on. The first equation should be written as $|a \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i | e_i \rangle . $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since $B=\{e_i\}$ for all $1\le i\le N$ is orthogonal basis, thus by hypothesis inner product of $e_i\, \& \, e_j$ for all $i,j$ is just $\delta_{ij}$ that is if $i=j$ then $<e_i|e_j>=1$ otherwise $<e_i|e_j>=0$

Thus in this case, for $a = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i e_i$ we get

\begin{align}
\langle e_j|a\rangle&= \sum_{i=1}^N\langle e_j|a_i e_i\rangle\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \langle e_j|e_i\rangle \\ 
&= a_j &&\text{(Since, only $i=j$ term survives)}.
\end{align}

Comment: This older post helps a bit as well: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133441/inner-products-with-orthonormal-bases?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

By definition of an orthonormal basis, given any two vectors $e_i$ and $e_j$ of that basis we have $\langle e_i|e_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta.

Comment: Including a definition of the Kronecker delta and how it simplifies the evaluation of sums might clarify things further.

Comment: @HansWurst I believe this is a better answer to *help* the OP learn. If the OP doesn't know what a Kronecker delta is, they should go look it up. This answer leads in the right direction but doesn't "give away the store."